# Can you change the default wine theme?

Tags: windows, wine, themes

There is a [great ambiance theme](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/ubuntu-ambiance-theme-for-windows-xp-wine/) for wine and windows that I use. But when I create a new wine prefix (or use PlayOnLinux to do so) it uses the default ugly grey-and-blue windows 95 theme.

Is there a way to change wine into automatically using my own theme, i.e. the ambiance theme for new wine prefixes?

Comment: there was a recent life hacker article about changing wine themes. http://lifehacker.com/5677881/make-wine-apps-match-your-gtk-theme-with-a-python-script

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Roland is right, you are probably best doing this manually at the moment.

However, it is possible to change Wine's system-wide default registry settings by editing /usr/share/wine.inf -- this is the registry that new Wine Prefixes get created with.  I'm not sure how to add a theme in there, although you could look at the registry of a current Wine install after you change the theme for hints.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make wine use this theme automatically, due to limitations in both Wine and Playonlinux. If you look into your `~/.Playonlinux` directory you will see that there are wine versions downloaded by Playonlinux, but unfortunately, the format they are in doesn't make it possible to apply a theme in this manner.

Your best bet is to apply the theme to your prefixes manually after installation, and possibly to make a request on the [Playonlinux forums](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/forums.html) for such a feature.