# Cannot install.msstyles theme on wine

Tags: wine, themes, itunes

I can't install my *Windows aero msstyles theme* in *wine*.

I used *PlayOnLinux* to install *iTunes 10* and during the installation, it installed a *Royale theme* and was in Windows XP.

I went to configure wine and clicked install theme and selected my file and when I went to the dropdown menu there was no option to select my theme.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you change the default wine theme?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11811/can-you-change-the-default-wine-theme)

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. Looking for a solution...

Comment: My theme file was broken- i downloaded a different one and it worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be sure of the Wine settings you are changing: on PlayOnLinux you can have several versions of Wine running, and each version can have different settings.